# Testing for WordPress custom post type variables

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Within the array for a custom post type named rg_story that I am defining, I have the following statement:

```
'chronological' => true,
```

Later, I have this:

```
if ( 'rg_story' == get_post_type()) {
```

As far as I know, everything is working OK. I'll know for sure once I create my templates. This is my first time with this stuff.

The problem is that I would like to test for the value of 'chronological', rather than the specific post type. I'm just not sure which function would do that.

Comment: your question is not clear. check this link for register a custom post type https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type .

Where you defined `'chronological' => true`?

Comment: I have checked the Codex, and haven't found what I'm looking for. Not sure what about my question is unclear. I have not provided all of my code, because much of it is irrelevant to the question, and would only be a distraction.

I would like to replace 'rg_story' == get_post_type() with a test that determines whether 'chronological' is true or false.

It so happens that I am doing this in the functions.php file of my theme, but it could as well be a plugin. The issue is the same.

Comment: so you are creating an Associative array. `$array = array('chronological' => true);`
to check it you can write
` if($array['chronological']){
//what to do
}`